# Ionic app takes too much time to load on android nexus 5X

Tags: android, performance, ionic-framework, load, boot

I am developing an Ionic app, It works fine in other android devices even on iPhone, but on it takes too much time to load on android nexus 5X.

This is the screens showing for like 3-4 minutes

[image]

Then This screen shows up,

[image: Image2]

Then app finally loads.

Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Launch the app with chrome inspect device and then see how much time takes the deviceReady event. chrome://inspect/devices#devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking 4-5 minutes sounds like way too long. Without any further info there's not much we can do to find out, but adding `--prod` flag is sure to help a lot.

`ionic run android --prod`

Comment: This boosts up some time, still taking 3 minutes, might be phone related issue?

Comment: If the issue does not apply on other Android and ios devices, then I can only think it's some low level problem with the specific device. It might even be a problem with that exact device's configuration, meaning that some other nexus 5X might not have the issue.

Comment: Exactly, That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of the debug build in Android Studio.

Goto Build -> Build APK

Now install this apk on your device. It should work fine.

Comment: I don't use studio, I work with terminal only. App is fine with other devices , only problem with Nexus 5X

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to generate less size of apk file

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs
```